# Give circular background to image without cropping

Tags: css, image

I want to give a circular background to white image. My code looks like this:

```
.cs-ways img {
    display: block;
    background: #2B80C5;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 50px !important;
    border-radius: 50em;
    height: 50px !important;
    object-fit: initial;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

This gives the following result:
[image]

As you can see the white image is being cropped in a circular fashion. This not something I want, how to fix this? I must use an image lement

Comment: Just remove the img from your css. eg; .cs-ways {....} and ensure that your image is 50px by 50px.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this simply using clip-path - just add it to .cs-ways class and it will make circular clipping path - the parameter inside needs to be adjusted to your picture and layout - you can use percentages.

```
clip-path: circle(40%);
```